# Excel pivot table: display rows filtered, but keep total for all rows (unfiltered)

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have a pivot table where I filter the data by month. The thing is I need a total column for all months. Is it possible to somehow ignore a select column from being filtered? Or maybe there is a way to achieve it using calculated fields.

Example:

```
October  500 clicks
November 600 clicks
December 1000 clicks
```

I use filter: `November`

I get a table:

```
google | 600
```

What I want to get after using this filter:

```
google | 600 | 2100
```

[image]

Comment: If I understood well with so little, you want to keep the total unfiltered while filtering what is displayed? If it is that, you canNOT, sorry! ;)

Comment: @R3uK I've added a screenshot. Total unfiltered or calculated fields or anything, I just don't know how to achieve what I want.

Comment: it's unfortunately not possible with pivot table, but you may find workaround, e.g. hide the columns you don't need

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible directly. As the closest workaround I am aware of you may use the following:

1. Add a calculated column to your source data, calculating the sum of all the respective values

[image]

Explanation of the formula `=SUMIFS($C$2:$C$9,$A$2:$A$9,A2)`:

Sum all the values from the `C` column, where the respective value in the `A` column matches the value in the `A2` cell. So it is effectively equivalent with

```
= C2 + C4 + C6 + C8
```

2. Create the pivot table with an extra field Total, displayed as Max (or Min, it doesn't matter as it always contains the same value):

[image]

3. Without filtering it contains all the months:

[image]

4. Now you may filter your months:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, my pivot table is created from SQL query.

Comment: One thing you could do is bring the SQL data into a sheet by its self. Add the formula there and create a pivot table off the data.